# Code completion (Control + SPACE) doesn't work when Lombok is enabled with IntelliJ Idea and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2023.1 and Android Studio Flamingo. When I've installed Lombok by coping it to plugin folder instead of from market place (because is not available) I've noticed that Control + SPACE - auto completion code doesn't work. Sometimes after several times it works, but for some cases. Especially doesn't work for SDK methods. When I disabled Lombok plugin in Settings and restarted auto completion works, but I cannot use Lombok because IDE cannot resolve methods generated by Lombok. You don have the same problem? Any solution/workaround?

edit: Log form IDE:

```
2023-05-30 21:36:40,868 [  70293] SEVERE - #c.i.c.c.CompletionProgressIndicator - 'boolean com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor.semicolonNeeded(com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor, com.intellij.psi.PsiFile, int)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionContributor.semicolonNeeded(com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor, com.intellij.psi.PsiFile, int)'
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.CustomLiveTemplateBase.addCompletions(CustomLiveTemplateBase.java:39)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.showCustomLiveTemplates(LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.java:173)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplateCompletionContributor$1.addCompletions(LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.java:96)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProvider.addCompletionVariants(CompletionProvider.java:23)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(CompletionContributor.java:155)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributor(CompletionService.java:81)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.impl.CompletionServiceImpl.lambda$getVariantsFromContributor$0(CompletionServiceImpl.java:333)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.impl.CompletionServiceImpl.getVariantsFromContributor(CompletionServiceImpl.java:332)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:73)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.performCompletion(CompletionService.java:132)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.BaseCompletionService.performCompletion(BaseCompletionService.java:48)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.impl.CompletionServiceImpl.lambda$performCompletion$1(CompletionServiceImpl.java:351)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.impl.CompletionServiceImpl.performCompletion(CompletionServiceImpl.java:340)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.lambda$calculateItems$11(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:870)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.calculateItems(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:866)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.runContributors(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:854)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CodeCompletionHandlerBase.lambda$startContributorThread$7(CodeCompletionHandlerBase.java:374)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$tryReadOrCancel$5(CompletionThreading.java:169)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.tryReadOrCancel(CompletionThreading.java:167)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CodeCompletionHandlerBase.lambda$startContributorThread$8(CodeCompletionHandlerBase.java:365)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$startThread$0(CompletionThreading.java:92)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$startThread$1(CompletionThreading.java:88)
2023-05-30 21:36:40,869 [  70294] SEVERE - #c.i.c.c.CompletionProgressIndicator - Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 3  Build #AI-231.7864.76.2311.10101468
2023-05-30 21:36:40,869 [  70294] SEVERE - #c.i.c.c.CompletionProgressIndicator - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-05-30 21:36:40,869 [  70294] SEVERE - #c.i.c.c.CompletionProgressIndicator - OS: Mac OS X
```

SOLVED:
On GitHub there is working Lombok plugin for Android Studio Flamingo -> https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1111

Comment: Any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: Log attached in post.

Comment: Resolved. Lombok for the newest version of IntelliJ and Android Studio is not supported. I installed older version of Android Studio (4.4.2 last supported version) and issue doesn't occurs.

Comment: Lombok plug-in is bundled with the latest IntelliJ IDEA versions. you do not need to install it.

Comment: I need to use Android Studio unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you need Lombok?  IntelliJ can auto-generate all that stuff.  Record classes make lots of it superfluous.  Lombok is a bad idea.  I'd remove it.